# Elementary problem in electrostatics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, energy-conservation, coulombs-law

> There are two charged particles of the same mass and have charges of opposite signs but of the same magnitude. If they are kept at a finite distance and then released, then find the speeds of both the particles once they are at half that distance.

When I read this, I thought that both has the same magnitude corresponding to every known quantity given here so they must collide at the center.

Since both the particles were moving towards each other, I assumed that the force acting over both of them are no longer constant but changing with distance as they approach together.

I tried to calculate their relative accelerations-apparently I think it is the sum of both their individual accelerations. Then I did some calculus and found the relative velocity of the particle.

I am not so well versed with calculus in the first place, but I think we use it to 'approximate' conditions and do some manipulation to figure out the entire problem.

However, the book used basic calculations (kinematics-uniform acceleration) to get the answer.

Is there something big that I am missing here?

Comment: Use the idea that electric potential energy will be changed into kinetic energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general there are two ways to approach problems like this.

The first way is to solve the equations of motion so you can get the position and velocity as functions of time. In that case you need to write down the force as a function of the distance between the particles, then use Newton's second law $F=ma$ to give you a differential equation for the acceleration:

$$ a = \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \frac{F(x)}{m} $$

The trouble is that this often leads to equations that are hard to solve. If we have to do this way then, well, we just have to grind through all the maths and as you say this does involve calculus.

But if you aren't concerned with the time dependence and all you want is the velocity as a function of distance there is an easy way to get this. The charges are initially stationary so their kinetic energy is zero, and the total energy, $E$, is just the potential energy, $V$. The total energy is conserved so we know it must be equal to the sum of the potential and kinetic energy, $T$:

$$ E = V + T $$

So the kinetic energy is just:

$$ T = E - V $$

When the charges move their potential energy changes, and that means you can calculate the change in the kinetic energy. And since the kinetic energy is just $\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2$ you can (if the symmetry allows) calculate the velocity of the charges.

To illustrate this we'll consider the example you give. If the initial separation is $x$ then the potential energy (and the total energy) is:

$$ E = V = -\frac{kQ^2}{x} $$

And when they have moved halfway towards each other, so the separation is $x/2$, the potential energy changes to:

$$ V' = -\frac{kQ^2}{x/2} = -2\frac{kQ^2}{x} $$

Which means the kinetic energy is just:

$$ T = V - V' = \frac{kQ^2}{x} $$

And because the setup is symmetric the velocities and kinetic energies of the two charges are the same so you get:

$$ 2 \times \tfrac{1}{2}mv^2 = \frac{kQ^2}{x} $$

And you can solve for $v$.